# Elegant proof that a rational function has no essential singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis

Theorem III of [Townshends Complex Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=VuGbwcRp_pEC&pg=PA293&lpg=PA293&dq=rational+function+has+no+essential+singularities&source=bl&ots=2bIKcOvLNL&sig=MGogSdoY_5ZXpr8l49hIKSGaMig&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PualT5n0FuWuiQKG2M2cAg&ved=0CGAQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=rational%20function%20has%20no%20essential%20singularities&f=false) has a proof that rational functions have no essential singularities.

Just wondering, are there any particularly elegant proofs that a rational function has no essential singularities?

Comment: They are quotients of polynomials, which are meromorphic functions on the sphere—therefore rational functions are also meromorphic on the sphere. This reduces to checking that polynomials have a pole at $\infty$, which is easy; for example, they grow polynomially :)

Comment: @Mariano: Assuming they have a singularity at $\infty$, i.e. are not constant. :)

Comment: Yeah, that :D (Well... constant polynomials have *at most* a pole at infinity :) )

Comment: Do you pdf file of this book?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since any rational function is of the form $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$, where $p,q$ are polynomials, the only singularities of $f(z)$ are the zeroes of $q(z)$ and $\infty$. $q(z)$ is a polynomial, hence all it's zeros are of finite order - so they are poles of that order (assuming $f$ is reduced, i.e. $p,q$ have no common zeroes). Depending on the degrees of $p,q$ it is easy to check that $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)$ is either $0$, $\infty$ or the quotient of the leading coefficients of $p,q$. In any case it exists, so $\infty$ can not be essential singularity.